# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estoy realizando el curso de udemy de ruby on rails y tengo este error

> ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass)

Acá tengo definido el método:

```
def full_name
return "#{first_name} #{last_name}" if first_name || last_name
  "anonymous"
end
```

Este es mi partial _friend_result.html.erb

```
<% if @friends %>
    <div class="card card-header result-search">
    <% @friends.each do |friend| %>
      <strong>Name: </strong><%= @friend.full_name %> 
      <strong>Email: </strong><%= @friend.email %> 
      <strong>Actions </strong><%= link_to "View Profile", '#', class:"btn btn-small btn-success"%>
      <%= link_to 'Follow', '#',
                                    class:"btn btn-success", method: :post  %>  
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás definiendo la variable `friend` a través de esta iteración

```
<% @friends.each do |friend| %>
```

sin embargo después estás llamando a `@friend` que es una variable de instancia que no has definido ninguna parte, por lo tanto te retorna `nil`. La forma correcta sería:

```
  <strong>Name: </strong><%= friend.full_name %> 
  <strong>Email: </strong><%= friend.email %>
```